# scollbar not correct in overflown flex object when justifing content

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I am to justify-content to space-around in a container smaller than the internal items.

It seems to partially work, however, the start of the items are outside the bounds.

my main problem is I have some HTML like this.

```css
    .container{
          display:flex;
          flex-direction:row nowrap;
          overflow:auto;
          gap: 5px;
          background:gray;
        }
        .space-around {
          justify-content: space-around;
        }
        .item{
          position:relative;
          min-width:100px;
          min-height:100px;
          background:red;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="container space-around" style="width:800px;">
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
      <div class="item">5</div>
      <div class="item">6</div>
      <div class="item">7</div>
      <div class="item">8</div>
      <div class="item">9</div>
    </div>
```

result ok as long as the container is wider than the internal sum of the items, however.. when the container is smaller, I get this:
[image]

my scenario is that the items are in a dynamic range, so I can't even brute-force the numbers and add left padding.

Does anyone else has this problem, and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

use `space-between` it will add space evenly

```css
    .container{
          display:flex;
          flex-direction:row nowrap;
          overflow:auto;
          gap: 5px;
          background:gray;
        }
        .space-between {
          justify-content: space-between;
        }
        .item{
          position:relative;
          min-width:100px;
          min-height:100px;
          background:red;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="container space-between" style="width:800px;">
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
      <div class="item">5</div>
      <div class="item">6</div>
      <div class="item">7</div>
      <div class="item">8</div>
      <div class="item">9</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: your solution is a good candidate, but I also wanted the space before the first item and after the last item, to centre them evenly in the middle, when only 1 or 2 items was present. the space-between sadly only add the dynamic space between items.

Comment: @Droa then add the total width of outer container greater than otal number of divs

Comment: that require the children to be a fixed count.